# Projection, rotation and skew-symetry in N-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Is it a true proposition that composition of a projection onto any $2$-dimensional plane **$\epsilon_2$** and rotation by angle $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ in this plane gives always **skew-symmetric** matrix independently from dimension of a space where projection is executed ?
In the other words:

if $ S = Proj_{\epsilon_2}Rot_{\epsilon_2}(\dfrac{\pi}{2})$,   then $S=-S^T$.

How to prove it ?

It is also equivalent to the statement that matrix made from
vectors of the basis **${e_1 ~ e_2~ e_3~  ... e_n} $** projected onto 2-dimensional
plane and rotated by $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is **skew-symmetric**.

It is possible, I suppose, to use property of *commutativity* of projection and rotation proved earlier, but it might be only one step (probably decisive) towards  **skew-symmetry**.

**After 4 hours**

It seems I have worked out the proof.
$Proj_{\epsilon_2}$ can be written as $aa^T+bb^T$ where $a$ , $b$ are defining orthogonal unit vectors for 2-dimensional plane.
We have

$ S^T = (Proj_{\epsilon_2}Rot_{\epsilon_2}(\dfrac{\pi}{2}))^T=(Rot_{\epsilon_2}(\dfrac{\pi}{2}))^TProj_{\epsilon_2}^T= (Rot_{\epsilon_2}(\dfrac{\pi}{2}))^{-1}(aa^T+bb^T)^T=(Rot_{\epsilon_2}(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}))(aa^T+bb^T)= -Rot_{\epsilon_2}(\dfrac{\pi}{2})Proj_{\epsilon_2}=-S$

As we see projection and rotation (simple rotation by ${\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$) give always **skew-symmetric** matrix.

Opened **NEW** question is whether **any skew-symmetric** matrix (N-dimensional) can be decomposed to a projection matrix (up to the scale) and rotation (maybe not always simple one) in N-dimensional space.

In 2-d and 3-d space it seems it is always possible.

**After 2  months**

> I still don't have an answer for the question above:
>
> is n-dimensional skew-symmetric matrix **always** decomposable into some rotation matrix and other, maybe projection or not ? (or maybe this property is limited only to 2 and 3 D?)

Comment: See related question posed by the same author yesterday http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1778434

Comment: Yes, it is related and  I need a proof for **any** 2-dimensional plane not a particular one.

Comment: It looks like by “projection” you specifically mean orthogonal projection relative to the usual Euclidean scalar product.

Comment: @Widawens it's a duplicate in the sense that the answer given in that post is applicable to this.

Comment: "This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question". First answer is not the answer for the question above. How could you not see that ? I don't understand. It's the different question though related. Where do you have in the first question issue of skew-symmetric matrix, could you tell me that ???

Comment: @Aegis:  "the answer given in that post is applicable to this" - what do you mean by that ??  - question was different and that answer is only suitable for previous question because **commutativity and skew-symmetry** are different properties.

Comment: @Widawens Yes but the answer boils down to the same thing. In the post flagged as duplicate, JeanMarie expresses the projection in a simple form by using  a particular basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. From that, you can see that the product of the two matrices is equal to the rotation matrix, which is skew-symmetric for $\theta = \pi/2$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Widawens Ah, you said you want a proof for *any* two-dimensional plane. This is something the proof doesn't make very clear. He implicitly uses the fact that you can chose whatever basis you wish for $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's a bit long to explain in a comment if you are not familiar with the idea; I can post a more detailed answer on the duplicate post if you wish.

Comment: @Aegis. Yes, I wanted any two-dimensional plane. JeanMarie used the special case. O.K, please Aegis explain how to transform skew-symetric matrix from JeanMarie's answer to the other one for arbitraily chosen plane. I also have added question whether skew-symetric M. can be decomposed into projection matrix and rotation - however it change nothing in the label "exact duplicate".

Comment: @Aegis. I set up a new question in linear algebra today, maybe you could take a look on it. To have such a list, like mentioned in it, it could shorten a lot of work ;)