# Geometric interpretation of a hollow symmetrical 3D matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Any matrix $A$ can be presented as a sum of its symmetrical and skew-symmetrical part:

$A=sym(A)+skew(A)$.

Decomposition can go further and we can present symmetrical part as a sum of some diagonal matrix and hollow (zeros on diagonal) symmetrical matrix. Now we have (used below notation is only for the needs of this question)

$A= diag(A)+hols(A)+ skew(A)$.

Let's assume the dimension of $A$ is $3$.

In this case we have the sum of   $3$ components where every component has $3$ DOF (decoded in three 3D vectors). We can also present these components in the form

$A= k_d{diag_n}(A )+k_h{hols_n}(A )+ k_s{skew_n}(A )$,

where coefficients

$k_d, k_h, k_s$

are  calculated so to assure that vectors which represent DOF of components are **unit vectors**, index $n$ denotes here this kind of "normalization"
 (so in these unit vectors we have decoded 2 degrees of freedom and additional DOF is in the appropriate scaling coefficient $k_{\{d,h,s)\}}$)

Example of such decomposition:

$\begin{bmatrix}  
1 & 3 & 5 \\
1 & 4 & 4 \\
1 & 8 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$ = 
9$\begin{bmatrix}  
\dfrac{1}{9} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \dfrac{4}{9} & 0 \\
0 &0 & \dfrac{8}{9}
\end{bmatrix}$+
7$\begin{bmatrix}  
0 & \dfrac{2}{7} & \dfrac{3}{7} \\
\dfrac{2}{7} & 0 & \dfrac{6}{7} \\
\dfrac{3}{7} & \dfrac{6}{7}  & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$+
3$\begin{bmatrix}  
0 & \dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} \\
-\dfrac{1}{3} & 0 & -\dfrac{2}{3} \\
-\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

**Two of components** have distinct geometric interpretation:
$diag(A)$ is simply a scaling matrix and $skew(A)$ is a scaled composition of a projection and  rotation by $\pi/2$ [(See question*)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779342/projection-rotation-and-skew-symetry-in-n-dimensional-space).
However **the geometric interpretation** for the $hols_n(A)$ is unknown to me..
In the general case matrix  $hols(A)$ has a form

$\begin{bmatrix}  
0 & a & b \\
a & 0 & c \\
b & c & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Some properties of this matrix    maybe  provide some information about its nature:

- it has real eigenvalues (as a special case of symmetric matrix) so
  rotation probably can't be engaged for this interpretation (unless it
  is by $\pi$)
- determinant of this matrix  $det(hols(A))= 2abc$ so its rank $=3$      if $ a,b,c \neq 0$. If one of $a,b,c=$ $0$ its rank decreases
  (*unlike $skew_n(A)$ where zeroing a single entry (and its skew-symmetrical one) doesn't change geometric interpretation - only axis of rotation which determines at the same time the direction of projection*).
- few others  are  [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix).

So my **question** is:

> - Could   hollow symmetrical matrix $hols_n(A)$ be decomposed in such a way that geometric    interpretation of $hols_n(A)$ would be explicit ?

*If geometric interpretation of the hollow matrix is too difficult one can propose other method for decomposition of symmetrical part $sym(A)$ only on condition that both parts should have 3 DOF and each part should have explicit geometric interpretation..*

Comment: The diagonal-hollow decomposition is not basis independent. When you extract the hollow part, you have chosen a coordinate frame. If the hollow part has any geometric meaning, its significance may be limited to this particular coordinate frame only.

Comment: @user1551 hmm, what about a standard frame?

Comment: @usser1  eigenvalues for this part would be the same after the change of frame? If so  properties of this matrix would be somehow preserved..

Comment: The obvious property is that each basis vector is mapped to a vector orthogonal to it.

Comment: Ok, could we extend this property somehow for transformations, for example, of cubes with unit sides?

Comment: I think you'd get a more interesting and geometrically meaningful decomposition if you decompose the matrix into a diagonal part, a symmetric **trace-free** part, and an anti-symmetric part.  The diagonal part would be proportional to the trace, which is basis independent.

Comment: @Muphrid Do you have some idea ?

Comment: @Muphrid "a symmetric trace-free part" - its' unclear for me Muphrid, what do you mean exactly by this in the context of the problem?

Comment: @Widawensen A symmetric matrix that has zero trace. The trace is a geometrical invariant, so decomposing based on separating out the trace--instead of enforcing the stricter condition that the symmetric part has zeroes on the diagonal--lends itself better to a geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that much like skewsymmetric matrices, symmetric hollow matrices have a similar geometrical/group theoretical interpretation.

Start from dimension $d = 2$, then the only symmetric hollow matrix $\sigma_1$ and the only skewsymmetric matrix $\sigma_2$ are
$$\sigma_1 =
\left[
     \begin{array}{cc}
             0 & 1 \\
             1 & 0
     \end{array}
\right], \quad
\sigma_2 =
\left[
     \begin{array}{cc}
             0 & 1 \\
             -1 & 0
     \end{array}
\right]$$
where we used the notation to coincide with that of the [Pauli' matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), up to a $\sigma_2 \to i \sigma_2$ to make it Hermitian.

Notice that $\sigma_1$ is the [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) of two elements, namely
$$ \sigma_1 \vec{x} = 
\left[
     \begin{array}{cc}
             0 & 1 \\
             1 & 0
     \end{array}
\right]
\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
             x \\
             y
     \end{array}
\right] = 
\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
             y \\
             x
     \end{array}
\right].
$$

So, it swaps the axes of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This operation leaves the norm of any vector invariant $||\sigma_1 \vec{x}|| = \sqrt{y^2 + x^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = ||\vec{x}||$. This means that $\sigma_1 \in O(2)$ is an [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) transformation, but it is not a rotation, since $\det[\sigma_1] = -1$.

For $d \geq 3$, just as you pointed out with skewsymmetric matrices, they can be projected and then rotated, in the case of symm hollow matrices they can be projected and swapped.

For example, $hols(A)$ in $d = 3$
\begin{align}
\left[
     \begin{array}{ccc}
             0 & x_{1, 2} & x_{1, 3} \\
             x_{1, 2} & 0 & x_{2, 3} \\
             x_{1, 3} & x_{2, 3} & 0
     \end{array}
\right]
\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
             x \\
             y \\
             z
     \end{array}
\right] & =
\left(
x_{1, 2}
\left[
     \begin{array}{cc|c}
             0 & 1 & 0 \\
             1 & 0 & 0 \\
             \hline
             0 & 0 & 0
     \end{array}
\right] +
x_{1, 3}
\left[
     \begin{array}{c|c|c}
             0 & 0 & 1 \\
             \hline
             0 & 0 & 0 \\
             \hline
             1 & 0 & 0
     \end{array}
\right] +
x_{2, 3}
\left[
     \begin{array}{c|cc}
             0 & 0 & 0 \\
             \hline
             0 & 0 & 1 \\
             0 & 1 & 0
     \end{array}
\right]
\right)
\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
             x \\
             y \\
             z
     \end{array}
\right], \\
 = & 
x_{1, 2}
\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
             y \\
             x \\
             0
     \end{array}
\right] +
x_{1, 3}
\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
             z \\
             0 \\
             x
     \end{array}
\right] +
x_{2, 3}
\left[
     \begin{array}{c}
             0 \\
             z \\
             y
     \end{array}
\right].
\end{align}
Here the matrix with coefficient $x_{1, 2}$ projects to the plane $\vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2$ (canonical basis) and swaps $\vec{e}_1 \leftrightarrow \vec{e}_2$. You can read this from the fact that $hols(A)$ is made of $\sigma_1$ and permutations of it for the other entries.

It is easy to see that the same thing happens with skewsymmetric matrices, they are permutations of $\sigma_2$, one for each plane.

A word or two about basis dependence. As pointed out in the comments this is basis dependent. Nevertheless, if we stick to orthogonal transformations $O(d)$ then, the interpretation still applies. The subtlety is that the swapping might be on different planes.

Comment: Very valuable interpretation. $9$ DOF ( $3\times  3$) of 3D matrix clearly geometrically visible.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a **note aside**, if instead of making it hollow, you fill the diagonal with $f_{1,\,2,\,3} (a,b,c)$
then you can get some significant factorization. For example:
$$
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & a & b  \\
   a & {1 + a^2 } & c  \\
   b & c & {1 + b^2  + (c - ab)^2 }  \\
 \end{array} } \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & 0 & 0  \\
   a & 1 & 0  \\
   b & {c - ab} & 1  \\
 \end{array} } \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & a & b  \\
   0 & 1 & {c - ab}  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
 \end{array} } \right)
$$

Now, doing that, the 3 DOF are preserved ; but, taking them out of the diagonal matrix,  the DOF there get increased.
I presume it is related to @user1551's note, but there is much to dig about..

Comment: Interesting symmetry in your decomposition, you are right, maybe others forms of matrices for decomposition of symmetrical part are more interesting (on the condition that we have 3 DOF preserved). Complementing diagonal form always is easy for interpretation.. just particular kind of scaling ... how  would you be interpreting geometrically these triangular matrices above ?

Comment: @Widawensen, that was just the first "interesting object" coming out from a very first digging ! then, by e.g. putting $c=a(b+1)$ it simplifies further, and acquire a more clear meaning, but .. ODF lower to 2. So a very interesting subject, with many facets to explore: thanks for proposing. We'll keep in touch for the outcomings.

Comment: Can we regard these 3 matrices in decomposition as some kind of "basis" for 3D matrix ? Family of 3D matrices can be composed from them just as a linear combination..

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is and *additive* transformation of coordinates.

$$
\mathbf{A} = diag\left( \mathbf{A} \right) + hollow\left( \mathbf{A} \right) 
$$
corresponds to that
the new vector $\mathbf{x}' = \left( {x'_1 ,x'_2 ,x'_3 } \right)$ 
is built first by $\left( {x'_1 ,0 ,0 } \right)$ (which is parallel to $\mathbf{x}$ )
plus $ \left( {0 ,x'_2 ,x'_3 } \right)$  (which is normal to $\mathbf{x}$ and to the previous step). Same for  $\mathbf{y}'$ and  $\mathbf{z}'$.
So a *general Hollow* matrix brings each base vector onto the plane normal to it. That is a rotation of $\pi/2$ around an axis normal to $\mathbf{x}$ ($1$ DOF) and a stretch ($1$ DOF): tot. $6$ DOF.
Symmetric and Skew-symmetric components do the same projections of each axis onto a plane normal to it, but the DOFs split into $3$ per each component, due to interrelation among rotation axes and stretch factors.
Of course the interrelation is different between the two components, but in this interpretation I cannot see a clearcut among the two.

Comment: However I would not be touching the skew-symmetric part because it has  good geometrical interpretation. In the light of this question it would be interesting to think over what means for 3D matrix to have **geometric interpretation** - some matrices evidently have them easier to find, others are hard for finding. Maybe it is really some kind of condition which gives such possibility. Whatever it is, hollow symmetric has 3DOF and it is one of the simplest forms of this kind.